# Converting a query result into an key=>value pairs for a lookup table

Tags: php, mysql, lookup

My app has a number of lookup tables stored in a MySQL database that are used for various purposes such as a `select` element.

Unfortunately, the query results aren't in an easily-digestible format and need some massaging to be more useful to me.

For example, when you query one of the lookup tables for all values, you get an array like this:

```
 0 => ['level_id' => 1, 'level' => 'Trivial'],
 1 => ['level_id' => 2, 'level' => 'Moderate']
 2 => ['level_id' => 3, 'level' => 'Challenging'],
 3 => ['level_id' => 4, 'level' => 'Formidable']
```

But for my purposes, this is what I want:

```
 1 => 'Trivial',
 2 => 'Moderate',
 3 => 'Challenging',
 4 => 'Formidable'
```

(Note that the array keys are the same as the record id).

If the array has more than one additional column, the result will be contained in sub-arrays:

```
 3 => ['level' => 'Challenging', 'description' => 'Foobar'],
 4 => ['level' => 'Formidable', 'description' => 'Bazbat']
```

This is all *very* trivial, but I wrote this function that I'd like you to review to know if there is a better way to do this in PHP.

The function needs to be generic so it can use any lookup array without having to know the column names.

```
<?php
// Turn an array into a key=>value pair. Assumes the key is the first item in the sub-array.
public function column_into_keys(array $array): array {

    // get the name of the column that contains the record id
    $key = key($array[0]);

    foreach($array as $row) {

        // pop the new key off the top of the array
        $id = array_shift($row);

        // is there only one item left in the array?
        if (count($row) == 1)
            // get the first value
            $result[$id] = current($row);
        else
            // get all of the values
            $result[$id] = $row;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: array_column('level') will give you that http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php. Check out array_keys also for reference

Comment: @Indra, with `array_column()` I would need to explicitly indicate the column names, wouldn't I?

Comment: yeah, but that can be a variable. like in this case $column='level'. array_column($column) and you set that as needed

Comment: Unfortunately, I would also need to specify the column that contains my row id's for the key. My method above doesn't care about the names of the columns.

Comment: array_combine(array_column($col1), array_column($col2)) ? Ah.. this would be so much easier using collections. Or a combo of array_keys and array_values or an array_map should work.

Comment: But how would you know the value of `$col1` and `$col2`? I feel like you are just looking for an alternative way to do what I'm already doing. I would love to know if you think my existing solution is ineffective. If so, how?

Comment: Why is `$key` declared, but never used?  `array_combine(array_column($col1), array_column($col2))` is uninformed advice -- it is as simple as `array_column($array, 'level', 'level_id');`  I don't understand the meaning of the two rows with `description` in them.  How is that supposed to impact the earlier mentioned sample data?

Comment: @mickmackusa, the original code I posted was clipped from a larger function I wrote, and I fixed that mistake in an edit, but a senior member reverted all of my edits back to the original post and told me that I'm not supposed to modify the code I originally posted. I wish I could remove that extra line, but that's how it goes here I guess.

Comment: @mickmackusa, the extra "description" columns were just to demonstrate how I'd like to handle query results that contain more than two columns. If the result has two columns, I wanted a simple key=>value array. If the result had more columns, I wanted a key => array result. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you are working with PHP, there is no reason to neglect such a feature that **already exists in the language**.

For example when you query one of the lookup tables for all values,

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM lookup")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

you get an array like this:

```
 1 => 'Trivial',
 2 => 'Moderate',
 3 => 'Challenging',
 4 => 'Formidable'
```

all thanks to [PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR fetch mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR).

Of course it works only with PDO, but you are supposed to use this driver anyway.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of help I was hoping for. In my current case, I'm unfortunately working with a legacy CodeIgniter codebase that doesn't have that as part of it's database abstraction. But I now have a new useful tool in my belt.

Comment: One quick question: does this handle my second use case, where the array values could be arrays themselves?

Comment: yes of course, PDO has [PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE) mode as well

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$finalResult=[];
        array_map(function ($value) use (&$finalResult){
            $result = array_values($value);
            return $finalResult[$result[0]] = $result[1];
        }, $array);

        return $finalResult;
```

I try avoiding `for` as much as possible and rely on native functions. I started doing this since I read a book called *Refactoring to Collections*. This improved my code and the speed of my code.

Native functions are written in a memory effective way.

The function inside the `array_map` is called a *closure*. You can implement a closure anytime you need to do quick computations locally.

Your solution does the job right, but looks a little bit messy. I don't think there will be a speed issue with what you have though.

Edit:

```
 $array = [
            0 => ['level_id' => 1, 'level' => 'Trivial', 'description' => 'Foobar'],
            1 => ['level_id' => 2, 'level' => 'Moderate', 'description' => 'Foobar'],
            2 => ['level_id' => 3, 'level' => 'Challenging', 'description' => 'Foobar'],
            3 => ['level_id' => 4, 'level' => 'Formidable'],
        ];
```

Using this:

```
$finalResult = [];
        array_map(function ($value) use (&$finalResult) {
            $result = array_values($value);
            return sizeof($result) == 2 ?
                $finalResult[$result[0]] = $result[1]
                : $finalResult[$result[0]] = array_slice($value, 0, sizeof($value) - 1);
        }, $array);
```

You will always get the right answer no matter how many columns you have or how many combinations you have.

- `sizeof($result) == 2 ? $finalResult[$result[0]] = $result[1]` - if the array has 2 entries use the first as id and second as value.
- `$finalResult[$result[0]] = array_slice($value, 0, sizeof($value) - 1);` - if it has more than 2 entries then 2 entries remove the first (`array_slice($value, 0, sizeof($value) - 1)`). This does not cover the case where there is only one entry, but neither did yours. We should cover that as well like this:

  ```
  return sizeof($result) == 2 ?
                      $finalResult[$result[0]] = $result[1]
                      : sizeof($result) >  2 ? $finalResult[$result[0]] = array_slice($value, 0, sizeof($value) - 1) : [];
  ```

Now for the for issue:

What a `for` does is basically iterating through every item of the array (no matter how long) and do something with it. Ideally, native functions use memory addresses to find one element at the time, do something with it and free the memory. I said ideally, because sometimes whoever wrote the code threw a `for` behind it. I will try to write a blog post about this since it sounds like a great issue to raise.

Mostly, what I can tell you after 12 years of programming is that you learn by doing. And you usually learn when something does not work out. I learned my lesson with `for` after a server failed with 503 ( was having timeout issues) when my database reached a million entries or so.

It is great that you want to learn and improve and I think that if you stick to what you're doing you're gonna get there. Just don't be afraid to test and try other things. Whenever I have a similar issue I go to the manual and check what I can use. If no such function is in the manual I add it to my helpers file (that I import everywhere) and try it with lots of data. If it fails I go back and try other options.

Comment: I try avoiding fors as much as possible and rely on native functions. I think your result does the job nicely, these are just alternatives. I am pretty rusty with my php (using Laravel for 4 years), but when I did work in vanilla php I used to rely on these 4 functions like crazy: array_map, array_keys, array_values, array_column

Comment: Thank you for responding. But this doesn't address the case where the array contains more than one additional element. See the 3rd code block in the question.

Comment: @pbarney you're right. let me check another solution

Comment: Is your general thesis that using foreach loops are a bad idea? If so, why? I'm looking for wisdom to help me grow as a programmer.

Comment: check out my edit and feel free to give me feedback

Comment: also I made a mistake. use count() instead of sizeof() since is faster and they do the same thing

Comment: and as a final comment: don't be afraid to learn something new. I commented earlier that it would have been much easier with collections. Collections are a series of objects rather than an array and they are part of a framework called laravel. If you feel you are comfortable with your level of php you can do the next step and try a framework like laravel or symphony. As a final note I saw you named your function using slugcase. Try implementing PSR-2. I know PHP can be like the wild west  when it comes to standardization, but PSR-2 is widely accepted and implemented

Answer (score 2):

Array combine takes Keys + Values as values and combines them. Make sure they are the same size.

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_column($array, 'level_id'),
    array_column($array, 'level')
);
```

And also a nice trick with `array_map()` and NOT using a callback.

```
$test1 = [
    'first-1',
    'first-2',
    'first-3',
    'first-4',
];
$test2 = [
    'second-1',
    'second-2',
    'second-3',
    'second-4',
];
$result = array_map(null, $test1, $test2);
[
    [
        'first-1',
        'second-1'
    ],
    [
        'first-2',
        'second-2'
    ],
    ......
]
```

Comment: [`array_combine(array_column(), array_column())`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445492/2943403) is an antipattern.  I don't see any request for the technique of "array transposition" in the asked question.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the PDO functions (as pointed out [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/191408/50303) by @YourCommonSense) is the right approach *when querying from a database*.**

But in cases where the array doesn't originate from a database, the following is an optimized approach to the original question using a generic function that can use any array without having to know the column names, as long as the "key" column is first.

```
<?php
// Turn an array into a key=>value or key=>array pair.
// Assumes the key is the first item in the sub-array.
public function columnIntoKeys(array $array): array {
    
    // skip empty arrays
    if (! count($array)) return [];
    
    // loop through each result row
    foreach($array as $row) {
        
        // pop the value of the row identifier off the top of the array
        $id = array_shift($row); // O(n)
        
        // if there is only one item left in the array...
        $result[$id] = (count($row) == 1)
            ? current($row) // ...get the first value
            : $row;         // ...get the rest of the array
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It appears that, other than differences in comments, [the changes](https://www.diffchecker.com/GvIix0OE/) include 1. converting name from `kabob_case` into `camelCase`, 2. an early `return` statement when the array is empty and 3. a ternary operator inside the `foreach` instead of an `if` and `else` case. Is it "_optimized_" for those reasons? In what way(s) is it "_a generic function that can use any array without having to know the column names, as long as the "key" column is first_"?

Comment: What good is the `count()` check if the `foreach()` will already ignore an empty array and move straight to the return?  It could simply return an empty array by null coalescing `return $result ?? [];` if you didn't want to declare `$result = []` prior to looping.

Comment: A demo: https://3v4l.org/vgP3V